# Question on Functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $Y$ be a subspace of a Banach space $X$.

How can I show that there exists an 1-1 isometric map $\phi\colon Y^*\to X^*$ (need not be linear)?

Also, how can I show that $X^*|_{Y}=Y^*$? Here, $X^*|_{Y}$ is the set of restriction to $Y$ of all $f\in X^*$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: [Hahn-Banach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem) might be useful here.

Actually, I think it suffices if $X$ is a normed space, and $Y$ is a linear subspace.